# eclipse with docker tooling windows 10 pro; what is my TCP connection

Tags: eclipse, docker, tcp, eclipse-plugin, windows-10

My objective is to connect my eclipse with docker via the docker tooling plugin. Problem I'm having is with the TCP connection as I'm not sure what exactly to put in the dialog box. I'm following [this](http://blog.arungupta.me/docker-tools-eclipse/) tutorial and placed: `192.168.99.103:2376` but obviously I'm guessing (I thought it's the default). Any idea how can I get the correct TCP connection; the status of the connection is constantly on `Loading...`?

- The URI flips from TCP to https after clicking Finish.
- Using Windows 10 **pro**
- 

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The TCP connection is **http://localhost:2375**

Before testing the connection in Eclipse docker tool, go to the **Docker app Settings-General** and check the box: "**Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS**".

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this link and try to publish TCP to outside world so that it would not convert to HTTP:-

//docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports

Comment: **You may try this one also:-https://forums.docker.com/t/solved-connecting-windows-eclipse-with-docker-for-windows/13726

Answer (score 0):

If you are Using Docker Toolbox then:

The url might be "https://192.168.99.100:2376" or to check the IP of docker daemon, go to virtual box and click on VM called 'default'(or the docker machine name you are using) and check the IP in right bottom corner from network adapter icon.

If you are using 'Docker for Windows' then you have to expose your docker daemon on TCP.

Follow these steps:

Notification area >> Docker Icon >> Right click >> Settings >> General >> Choose the last option 'Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS'

Then the URL will be tcp://localhost:2375/6

If your plugin is not allowing to use TCP and forcing to use TLS then you have to expose your daemon with TLS.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/